# Partition an array into subsets of fixed size with minimum sum difference

Tags: algorithm, partitioning, subset-sum, array-algorithms

I have found versions of this problem for either `2` subsets of half the size of the original array or with any number of subsets of any length. Does anybody have any pointers to any good solution for this problem? (can be greedy)

Given an array of positive numbers of length `N` (can have repetitions)

Partition the `N` numbers into subsets of length `M` with their sum difference minimized.

Simple example:

```
N=9, M=2
[5, 2, 3, 7, 5, 3, 7, 8, 1]
into
[[8, 1], [7, 2], [7, 3], [5, 5]] + [3] (leftover)
   9        9      10      10
```

My real world use case is to group files of different sizes into batches of a given length but having the total size of each batch be as close as possible to that of the other batches.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the definition of sum difference?

Comment: That for every two pairs of subsets s1, s2 (both s1 and s2 have `M` elements) their absolute difference (`abs(sum(s1) – sum(s2))`) is minimized

Comment: what about the rules for leftover?

Comment: Should be of length `N % M` and its sum should be less or equal than the other subsets sum

Comment: Do you mean to minimize sum of differences for _all subsets_ or _excluding leftover_?

Comment: Ideally all subsets but would accept a solution where leftover is excluded

Comment: Note to self: Maybe this could be adapted https://github.com/facebookresearch/fairscale/blob/v0.1.7/fairscale/nn/pipe/balance/blockpartition.py